# If you throw a dice 5 times, what is the expected value of the square of the median?

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice, symmetry

My question: If you throw a dice 5 times, what is the expected value of the square of the median of the 5 results?

A slightly modified question would be: If you throw a dice 5 times, what is the expected value of the median? The answer would be 3.5 by symmetry.

For the square, it seems to be that symmetry does not hold anymore. Is there a "smart" way to solve this problem?

If there isn't a smart way to solve the problem, if there a smart way to estimate the answer?

Comment: @Masacroso the median of the 5 results of the throws

Comment: I get 8833/648 = 13.63117 for the average of the squared median, but nothing really smart about it (just working through multinomial probabilities and using symmetry).

Comment: You know that the answer should be less than the second moment of a single die roll, which is $91/6$, since the median of five rolls has the same EV as for one roll, but smaller variance.

Comment: @TickaJules: Avraham's answer gives the slightly different value $13.62346$, which turns out to be equal to $8828/648$. Is it possible that you miscalculated?

Comment: $105936 / 7776 \approx 13.623456790123457$ is correct: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b83e561e16d2680bc46ffdf1b5e95f8c

Comment: @DanielV: $105936/7776 = 8828/648 = 2207/162$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. r.v. If we order the previous list of r.v. by it values we get r.v. $X_{(1)},\ldots ,X_{(n)}$ named the ranks of the list $X_1,\ldots,X_n$. Now, observe that the distribution of the $k$-th rank of $n$ i.i.d. r.v. is given by

$$
\Pr [X_{(k)}\leqslant c]=\Pr \left[\bigcup_{r\geqslant k}(\{X_{(j)}\leqslant c, j\leqslant r\}\cap \{X_{(j)}>c,j\geqslant r+1\})\right]\\
=\Pr \left[\bigcup_{r\geqslant k}\bigcup_{A\in \mathcal{A}_r}(\{X_j\leqslant c, j\in A\}\cap \{X_j>c,j\in A^\complement \})\right]\\
=\sum_{r\geqslant k}\binom{n}{r}F_{X_1}(c)^r(1-F_{X_1}(c))^{n-r}
$$

with the convention that $0^0:=1$ and where $\mathcal{A}_r:=\{B\subset \{1,\ldots,n\}: |B|=r\}$. Now observe that the median, $M$, of five i.i.d. r.v. is just $X_{(3)}$ and

$$
\mathrm{E}[M^2]=\sum_{k= 1}^6 k^2p_M(k)=\sum_{k=1}^{6}k^2(F_M(k)-F_M(k-1))
$$

Therefore, putting all together and using a CAS we get the result $\mathrm{E}[M^2]=\frac{2207}{162}\approx 13.62$.

Answer (score 0):

This is small enough that it can be calculated explicitly through some code. Creating the matrix of throws is inefficient, but it should be clear to see how the universe of possibilities is spanned.

```
throws <- matrix(double(0), ncol = 5, nrow = 6^5)
throws[, 5] <- rep(1:6, each = 6^0, times = 6^4)
throws[, 4] <- rep(1:6, each = 6^1, times = 6^3)
throws[, 3] <- rep(1:6, each = 6^2, times = 6^2)
throws[, 2] <- rep(1:6, each = 6^3, times = 6^1)
throws[, 1] <- rep(1:6, each = 6^4, times = 6^0)
 
thrMed <- apply(throws, 1L, median) 
mean(thrMed)
[1] 3.5

mean(thrMed ^ 2)
[1] 13.62346
```

As stated in the comments, this is the expected squared median for five throws of dice. The symmetry no longer holds since $4^2 - 3.5^2 > 3.5^2 - 3^2$ and so on. Therefore the expected squared median is larger than the expected median squared.

Comment: "expected squared median is larger than the expected median squared" this is always true for any random variable, i.e. $\mathbb E[X^2]\geq\mathbb E[X]^2$, because their difference is the variance, which is non-negative. The inequality is strict so long as $X$ is not a.s. constant.